# hypersdkflutter - Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm integrating [hypersdkflutter](https://pub.dev/packages/hypersdkflutter) into a flutter app. As part of the setup, I have to change `FlutterActivity` to `FlutterFragmentActivity` in my `MainActivity.kt` file. Everything used to work before this change but after making this change, I'm getting following error

```
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>)' method. None of the following functions is suitable: 
public inline operator fun <T> Lazy<String>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String defined in kotlin
```

Full console log here - https://pastebin.com/1gzWC90F

This is what my `MainActivity.kt` looks like

```
package com.package_name

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    private val AUDIO_RECORDER_CHANNEL = "com.package_name/audio_recorder"
    private val SHARE_CHANNEL = "com.package_name/share"

    private val providerAuthority: String by lazy {
        context.packageName + ".package_name.share_provider"
    }

     override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        flutterEngine.plugins.add(ReceiveSharing())
        
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I found a [similar thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855008/kotlin-android-property-delegate-must-have-a-getvaluedashviewmodel-kproperty) but I'm unable to understand the problem.

I'm not fluent with Kotlin so any help or references to docs would be very helpful. Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. The problem was not with the missing getters or property delegate but it was because `context` and `activity` were not defined for `FlutterFragmentActivity`. Had to use replace them with `applicationContext` and `this` respectively.

Source - [getContext() and getActivity() with FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732732/getcontext-and-getactivity-with-fragmentactivity)